# elevation на старых API

Tags: android, xml, material-design

Начиная с API 21 android:elevation дает очень красивый эффект тени. Как добиться такого же результата для более старых версий android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать:

```
android:shadowColor, android:shadowDx, android:shadowDy, android:shadowRadius;
```

или

```
setShadowLayer()
```

Еще можно такое попробовать:
В файл ресурсов добавить:

```
<resources>
<color name="light_font">#FBFBFB</color>
<color name="grey_font">#ff9e9e9e</color>
<color name="text_shadow">#7F000000</color>
<color name="text_shadow_white">#FFFFFF</color>
```

Пример **TextView**:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_example1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textSize="14sp"
              android:textStyle="bold"
              android:textColor="@color/light_font"
              android:shadowColor="@color/text_shadow"
              android:shadowDx="1"
              android:shadowDy="1"
              android:shadowRadius="2" />
```

Или:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463747/simple-layout-shadow-in-android

Comment: метод setshadowlayer() работает с изображениями (класс Paint), а android:shadowDx работает только с textview. а нужно сделать тень к лейауту

Comment: @EugeneStrelnikov, обновил ответ, смотри ссылку